# How to assign DWORD value to LONGLONG variable?

Tags: c++, casting

I need to assign DWORD value to LONGLONG variable.

Can you assist with : How to assign DWORD value to LONGLONG variable ?

Thanks

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: Have you tried to assign?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and the compiler errors that you are seeing?

Comment: `DWORD d = 1234;  LONGLONG ll = d;`

Answer (score 2):

A `DWORD` variable is logicaly an integer of size less than a `LONGLONG` variable's.
And as if I'm still right, a `DWORD` is an unsigned variable, and even if a `LONGLONG` is signed, a `DWORD` value would not exceed the value of a `LONGLONG`.

So you should have no problem assigning a `DWORD` value to a `LONGLONG` variable, but the opposite would create some problems. Just do it like what you would do when assigning a variable to another.

Comment: Thanks, That's the answer I was expecting for !. Clear now.

Comment: @user2906743 the problem with your question was you never mentioned your concern.

Comment: @user2906743 please mark as resolved if it resolved your problem